# How to test if a file is a directory in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there any way to find out if a file is a directory?

I have the file name in a variable. In Perl I can do this:

```dos
if(-d $var) { print "it's a directory\n" }
```

Comment: Related: [How to test if a path is a file or directory in Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8666225)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
IF EXIST %VAR%\NUL ECHO It's a directory
```

However, this only works for directories without spaces in their names.  When you add quotes round the variable to handle the spaces it will stop working.  To handle directories with spaces, convert the filename to short 8.3 format as follows:

```
FOR %%i IN (%VAR%) DO IF EXIST %%~si\NUL ECHO It's a directory
```

The `%%~si` converts `%%i` to an 8.3 filename.  To see all the other tricks you can perform with `FOR` variables enter `HELP FOR` at a command prompt.

(Note - the example given above is in the format to work in a batch file. To get it work on the command line, replace the `%%` with `%` in both places.)

Comment: you forgot the d flag i think

Comment: It worked fine for me and what "D" flag?  Roman - The "D:" in your answer is a reference the "D:" drive on your machine.  Vhaerun - what did you have VAR set to when you tried this?

Comment: C:\sdf>if exist filethatexists\nul @echo wontdisplayanything  <-- try that, see here -->  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=u8trFYLf

Comment: **THIS DOES NOT WORK** with [Directory Symbolic Links (Softlinks) or Junctions](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html): Files whose path contains a Directory Link are misrecognized as Directory. To reproduce, type: <Win>`cmd` [<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Enter>](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/11/02/windows-vista-secret-10-open-an-elevated-command-prompt-in-six-keystrokes.aspx) `mklink /d LinkDir .` <Enter> `cd LinkDir` <Enter> `if exist regedt32.exe\nul echo File erroneously detected as Directory` <Enter> `rd .`

Comment: It doesn't work. However, adding a backslash at the end did work for me. For example: if exist "%~1\" echo It's a directory

Comment: MarioVilas is right.. On Windows 7 at least "\NUL" doesn't work. but just "\" works! Thanks!

Comment: This works: FOR %%i IN (%1) DO IF EXIST %%~si\* ECHO IS FOLDER

Comment: This also doesn't work for UNC paths (i.e. \\server\share\...). @Vhaerun: Please update your "accepted answer" mark to batchman61's one - that is the only robust answer on this page

Comment: Checking with NUL doesn't work on ReactOS, but checking with "%var%\\*" does.

Answer (score 111):

This works:

```dos
if exist %1\* echo Directory
```

Works with directory names that contains spaces:

```dos
C:\>if exist "c:\Program Files\*" echo Directory
Directory
```

Note that the quotes are necessary if the directory contains spaces:

```dos
C:\>if exist c:\Program Files\* echo Directory
```

Can also be expressed as:

```dos
C:\>SET D="C:\Program Files"
C:\>if exist %D%\* echo Directory
Directory
```

This is safe to try at home, kids!

Comment: This seems to be good, it even correctly handles empty folder correctly. Update: doesn't seem to require the '*' either, just the '\' on the end seems to be enough to verify that it is a folder.

Comment: Awesome, **this** even **works** with [Directory Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script#comment14656200_138995)! But **only with the `*`!!** (Also @GrantPeters)

Comment: Just in case the quotes are a problem, this works too: if exist "%~1\" echo It's a directory

Comment: This method does not work in Windows 10 20H2.

Comment: Great! Works for me even with UNC paths and drive letters mapped to network shares. Previously I used just \ which works for local files and dirs.

Comment: @CoolCmd Tested working on 20H2 and 21H1. Did you forget the asterisk or quotes?

Comment: @WildernessRanger, do not remember how i tested. at least it fail when running from Far Manager prompt.

Comment: @WildernessRanger It may fail in the cmd.exe prompt because the cmd.exe prompt has different rules for variables expansion.

Answer (score 74):

Recently failed with different approaches from the above. Quite sure they worked in the past, maybe related to dfs here. Now using the [files attributes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and cut first char

```dos
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set ATTR=%~a1
set DIRATTR=%ATTR:~0,1%
if /I "%DIRATTR%"=="d" echo %1 is a folder
:EOF
```

Comment: This is totally the best answer here... It even works if you don't have read permissions on the target file or directory (which is exactly what I needed). Thanks!

Comment: One of three solutions on this page that works:
isFile.bat example: http://pastebin.com/dmYKKa7M

Comment: Don't know why but my batch file does not expand `%1` to file/folder full path. I have to use `%~f1`. It expands paths like `.` and `..` to real path.

Comment: This is the best way because it uses documented features and therefore will work in future versions of Windows. For example, the method with most "likes" on this page does not work in Windows 10 20H2. But this one works.

Comment: @CoolCmd It works in Windows 10 22H2

Answer (score 12):

Further to my previous offering, I find this also works:

```
if exist %1\ echo Directory
```

No quotes around %1 are needed because the caller will supply them.
This saves one entire keystroke over my answer of a year ago ;-)

Comment: **THIS DOES NOT WORK** with [Directory Symbolic Links (Softlinks) or Junctions](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html): Files whose path contains a Directory Link are misrecognized as Directory. To reproduce, type: <Win>`cmd` [<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Enter>](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/11/02/windows-vista-secret-10-open-an-elevated-command-prompt-in-six-keystrokes.aspx) `mklink /d LinkDir .` <Enter> `cd LinkDir` <Enter> `if exist regedt32.exe\ echo File erroneously detected as Directory` <Enter> `rd .`

Answer (score 11):

Here's a script that uses FOR to build a fully qualified path, and then pushd to test whether the path is a directory.  Notice how it works for paths with spaces, as well as network paths.

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto usage

for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%~1") do set MYPATH="%%~fi"
pushd %MYPATH% 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto notdir
goto isdir

:notdir
echo not a directory
goto exit

:isdir
popd
echo is a directory
goto exit

:usage
echo Usage:  %0 DIRECTORY_TO_TEST

:exit
```

Sample output with the above saved as "isdir.bat":

```
C:\>isdir c:\Windows\system32
is a directory

C:\>isdir c:\Windows\system32\wow32.dll
not a directory

C:\>isdir c:\notadir
not a directory

C:\>isdir "C:\Documents and Settings"
is a directory

C:\>isdir \
is a directory

C:\>isdir \\ninja\SharedDocs\cpu-z
is a directory

C:\>isdir \\ninja\SharedDocs\cpu-z\cpuz.ini
not a directory
```

Comment: This works even with [Directory Symbolic Links (Softlinks) and Junctions](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html). (As opposed to the `\NUL` and `\` techniques.)

Comment: @accolade - what are the **\`\`** techniques ?

Comment: @KevinFegan (It looks like StackExchange changed the parsing of `\`…\`` inline code formatting.)  « `` » was supposed to be « ``\`` ».  I was referring to the the approach of appending a backslash at the end of the filename, e.g. proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script/143935?noredirect=1#answer-3845794

Answer (score 6):

This works perfectly

```
if exist "%~1\" echo Directory
```

we need to use %~1 to remove quotes from %1, and add a backslash at end. Then put thw whole into qutes again.

Comment: **THIS DOES NOT WORK** with [Directory Symbolic Links (Softlinks) or Junctions](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html): Files whose path contains a Directory Link are misrecognized as Directory. To reproduce, type: <Win>`cmd` [<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Enter>](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/11/02/windows-vista-secret-10-open-an-elevated-command-prompt-in-six-keystrokes.aspx) `mklink /d LinkDir .` <Enter> `cd LinkDir` <Enter> `if exist "regedt32.exe\" echo File erroneously detected as Directory` <Enter> `rd .`

Answer (score 4):

A variation of @batchman61's approach (checking the Directory attribute).

This time I use an external 'find' command.

(Oh, and note the `&&` trick. This is to avoid the long boring `IF ERRORLEVEL` syntax.)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
ECHO.%~a1 | find "d" >NUL 2>NUL && (
    ECHO %1 is a directory
)
```

Outputs yes on:

- Directories.
- Directory symbolic links or junctions.
- *Broken* directory symbolic links or junctions. (Doesn't try to resolve links.)
- Directories which you have no read permission on (e.g. "C:\System Volume Information")

Answer (score 4):

`CD` returns an `EXIT_FAILURE` when the specified directory does not exist. And you got [*conditional processing symbols*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455609/4510033), so you could do like the below for this.

```
SET cd_backup=%cd%
(CD "%~1" && CD %cd_backup%) || GOTO Error

:Error
CD %cd_backup%
```

Answer (score 3):

### The NUL technique seems to only work on 8.3 compliant file names.

#### (In other words, `D:\Documents and Settings` is "bad" and `D:\DOCUME~1` is "good")

---

I think there is some difficulty using the "NUL" tecnique when there are SPACES in the directory name, such as "Documents and Settings."

I am using Windows XP service pack 2 and launching the cmd prompt from %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe

Here are some examples of what DID NOT work and what DOES WORK for me:

(These are all demonstrations done "live" at an interactive prompt.  I figure that you should get things to work there before trying to debug them in a script.)

**This DID NOT work:**

`D:\Documents and Settings>if exist "D:\Documents and Settings\NUL" echo yes`

**This DID NOT work:**

`D:\Documents and Settings>if exist D:\Documents and Settings\NUL echo yes`

**This DOES work (for me):**

`D:\Documents and Settings>cd ..`

`D:\>REM get the short 8.3 name for the file`

`D:\>dir /x`

`Volume in drive D has no label.`
`Volume Serial Number is 34BE-F9C9`

`Directory of D:\`

`09/25/2008  05:09 PM    <DIR>                       2008`
`09/25/2008  05:14 PM    <DIR>          200809~1.25  2008.09.25`
`09/23/2008  03:44 PM    <DIR>          BOOST_~3     boost_repo_working_copy`
`09/02/2008  02:13 PM           486,128 CHROME~1.EXE ChromeSetup.exe`
`02/14/2008  12:32 PM    <DIR>                       cygwin`

[[Look right here !!!! ]]
`09/25/2008  08:34 AM    <DIR>          DOCUME~1     Documents and Settings`

`09/11/2008  01:57 PM                 0 EMPTY_~1.TXT empty_testcopy_file.txt`
`01/21/2008  06:58 PM    <DIR>          NATION~1     National Instruments Downloads`
`10/12/2007  11:25 AM    <DIR>                       NVIDIA`
`05/13/2008  09:42 AM    <DIR>                       Office10`
`09/19/2008  11:08 AM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files`
`12/02/1999  02:54 PM            24,576              setx.exe`
`09/15/2008  11:19 AM    <DIR>                       TEMP`
`02/14/2008  12:26 PM    <DIR>                       tmp`
`01/21/2008  07:05 PM    <DIR>                       VXIPNP`
`09/23/2008  12:15 PM    <DIR>                       WINDOWS`
`02/21/2008  03:49 PM    <DIR>                       wx28`
`02/29/2008  01:47 PM    <DIR>          WXWIDG~2     wxWidgets`
`3 File(s)        510,704 bytes`
`20 Dir(s)  238,250,901,504 bytes free`

`D:\>REM now use the \NUL test with the 8.3 name`

`D:\>if exist d:\docume~1\NUL echo yes`

`yes`

**This works, but it's sort of silly, because the dot already implies i am in a directory:**

`D:\Documents and Settings>if exist .\NUL echo yes`

Comment: The problem appears to be not with long file names but directories with spaces in their names.  Or rather, it's the quotes around the variable name that stop the NUL trick from working.  I've added some code to my answer which converts file names to 8.3 names before testing.

Comment: The NUL technique **DOES NOT WORK** with [Directory Symbolic Links (Softlinks) or Junctions](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html): Files whose path contains a Directory Link are misrecognized as Directory. To reproduce, type: <Win>`cmd` [<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Enter>](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/11/02/windows-vista-secret-10-open-an-elevated-command-prompt-in-six-keystrokes.aspx) `mklink /d LinkDir .` <Enter> `cd LinkDir` <Enter> `if exist regedt32.exe\nul echo File erroneously detected as Directory` <Enter> `rd .`

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
if not [%1] == [] (
  pushd %~dpn1 2> nul
  if errorlevel == 1 pushd %~dp1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

This works and also handles paths with spaces in them:

```
dir "%DIR%" > NUL 2>&1

if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo Directory exists.
) else (
    echo Directory does not exist.
)
```

Probably not the most efficient but easier to read than the other solutions in my opinion.

Comment: I liked your answer as the simplest. For some reason I don't understand it suddenly stopped working so I posted an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071300/how-to-create-a-batch-file-which-work-for-both-program-files-and-program-filesx/31095955#31095955).

Comment: Alternative take: if you can `cd` into it... of course, remember your current dir before `set cwd=%cd%` to restore later...

Comment: This verifies the path exists, but does not distinguish between a file or a folder.

Comment: The suggestion does not work for me. To fix it, use 
  `dir "%DIR%" /A:D > NUL 2>&1` to cause 
  `dir`
to exit with error code not equal to 0 for files.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way is to check if the child exists.

If a child does not have any child, the `exist` command will return false.

```
IF EXIST %1\. (
  echo %1 is a folder
) else (
  echo %1 is a file
)
```

You may have some false negative if you don't have sufficient access right (I have not tested it).

Comment: this is not working absolutly, try to test:
if exist C:\Windows\explorer.exe\. echo is folder

Answer (score 2):

If you can `cd` into it, it's a directory:

```
set cwd=%cd%

cd /D "%1" 2> nul
@IF %errorlevel%==0 GOTO end

cd /D "%~dp1"
@echo This is a file.

@goto end2
:end
@echo This is a directory
:end2

@REM restore prior directory
@cd %cwd%
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/msdos-programmer-faq/part3/section-7.html) titled "How can a batch file test existence of a directory" it's "not entirely reliable".

BUT I just tested this:

```
@echo off
IF EXIST %1\NUL goto print
ECHO not dir
pause
exit
:print
ECHO It's a directory
pause
```

and it seems to work

Comment: Reading the article "unreliable" means that it failed on Pathworks, Novell, DR-DOS and OS/2 which I doubt will be a problem for most people.

Comment: hence "not entirely reliable"

Comment: **THIS DOES NOT WORK** with [Directory Symbolic Links (Softlinks) or Junctions](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html): Files whose path contains a Directory Link are misrecognized as Directory. To reproduce, type: <Win>`cmd` [<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Enter>](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/11/02/windows-vista-secret-10-open-an-elevated-command-prompt-in-six-keystrokes.aspx) `mklink /d LinkDir .` <Enter> `cd LinkDir` <Enter> `if exist "regedt32.exe\NUL" echo File erroneously detected as Directory` <Enter> `rd .`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
REM make sure ERRORLEVEL is 0
TYPE NUL

REM try to PUSHD into the path (store current dir and switch to another one)
PUSHD "insert path here..." >NUL 2>&1

REM if ERRORLEVEL is still 0, it's most definitely a directory
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 command...

REM if needed/wanted, go back to previous directory
POPD
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post my own function script about this subject hope to be useful for someone one day.

```
@pushd %~dp1
@if not exist "%~nx1" (
        popd
        exit /b 0
) else (
        if exist "%~nx1\*" (
                popd
                exit /b 1
        ) else (
                popd
                exit /b 3
        )
)
```

This batch script checks if file/folder is exist and if it is a file or a folder.

**Usage:**

script.bat "PATH"

**Exit code(s):**

0: file/folder doesn't exist.

1: exists, and it is a folder.

3: exists, and it is a file.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with using `%%~si\NUL` method is that there is the chance that it guesses wrong. Its possible to have a filename shorten to the wrong file. I don't think `%%~si` resolves the 8.3 filename, but guesses it, but using string manipulation to shorten the filepath. I believe if you have similar file paths it may not work.

An alternative method:

```
dir /AD %F% 2>&1 | findstr /C:"Not Found">NUL:&&(goto IsFile)||(goto IsDir)

:IsFile
  echo %F% is a file
  goto done

:IsDir
  echo %F% is a directory
  goto done

:done
```

You can replace `(goto IsFile)||(goto IsDir)` with other batch commands:
`(echo Is a File)||(echo is a Directory)`

Comment: No, of course `%~s1` doesn't "guess"/string-manipulate the short file name, it resolves it correctly. Like `dir /x`

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 7 and XP, I can't get it to tell files vs. dirs on mapped drives.  The following script:

```
@echo off
if exist c:\temp\data.csv echo data.csv is a file
if exist c:\temp\data.csv\ echo data.csv is a directory
if exist c:\temp\data.csv\nul echo data.csv is a directory
if exist k:\temp\nonexistent.txt echo nonexistent.txt is a file
if exist k:\temp\something.txt echo something.txt is a file
if exist k:\temp\something.txt\ echo something.txt is a directory
if exist k:\temp\something.txt\nul echo something.txt is a directory
```

produces:

```
data.csv is a file
something.txt is a file
something.txt is a directory
something.txt is a directory
```

So beware if your script might be fed a mapped or UNC path.  The pushd solution below seems to be the most foolproof.

Comment: See also the solution from @batchman61 which avoids this issue by checking attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I use in my BATCH files

````
```
@echo off
set param=%~1
set tempfile=__temp__.txt
dir /b/ad > %tempfile%
set isfolder=false
for /f "delims=" %%i in (temp.txt) do if /i  "%%i"=="%param%" set isfolder=true
del %tempfile%
echo %isfolder%
if %isfolder%==true echo %param% is a directory
````

```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution after many tests with if exist, pushd, dir /AD, etc...

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /a /ogn /b') do (
    call :isdir "%%I"
    if errorlevel 1 (echo F: %%~fI) else echo D: %%~fI
)
cmd/k

:isdir
echo.%~a1 | findstr /b "d" >nul
exit /b %errorlevel%

:: Errorlevel
:: 0 = folder
:: 1 = file or item not found
```

- It works with files that have no extension
- It works with folders named folder.ext
- It works with UNC path
- It works with double-quoted full path or with just the dirname or filename only.
- It works even if you don't have read permissions
- It works with Directory Links (Junctions).
- It works with files whose path contains a Directory Link.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to only process directories then this will be useful.

This is taken from the https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

> Example... List every subfolder, below the folder C:\Work\ that has a name starting with "User":
>
> ```
> CD \Work
> FOR /D /r %%G in ("User*") DO Echo We found
> ```

`FOR /D` or `FOR /D /R`

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\your directory here"
for /d /r %%A in ("*") do echo We found a folder: %%~nxA
pause
```

Remove `/r` to only go one folder deep. The `/r` switch is recursive and undocumented in the command below.

The `for /d` help taken from command `for /?`

> FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory
>       names instead of file names.

Comment: This is an answer to another question. It doesn't fit to THIS question about detection if a given filename is a directory.

Comment: Seeing as the question has been answered to death. This just allows the user to process directories and skip the checking part.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this recently as well, and had stumbled upon a solution which has worked for me, but I do not know of any limitations it has (as I have yet to discover them).  I believe this answer is similar in nature to TechGuy's answer above, but I want to add another level of viability.  Either way, I have had great success expanding the argument into a full fledged file path, and I believe you have to use `setlocal enableextensions` for this to work properly.

Using below I can tell if a file is a directory, or opposite.  A lot of this depends on what the user is actually needing.  If you prefer to work with a construct searching for `errorlevel` vs `&&` and `||` in your work you can of course do so.  Sometimes an if construct for `errorlevel` can give you a little more flexibility since you do not have to use a `GOTO` command which can sometimes break your environment conditions.

```
@Echo Off
setlocal enableextensions

Dir /b /a:D "%~f1" && Echo Arg1 is a Folder || Echo Arg1 is NOT a Folder

Dir /b /a:-D "%~f1" && Echo Arg1 is a File || Echo Arg1 is NOT a File

pause
```

Using this you could simply drag and drop your file(s) onto the tool you are building to parse them out.  Conversely, if you are using other means to comb your file structure and you already have the file and are not dragging/dropping them onto the batch file, you could implement this:

```
@Echo Off
setlocal enableextensions


Dir /b /s "C:\SomeFolderIAmCombing\*" >"%~dp0SomeFiletogoThroughlater.txt"

For /f "Usebackq Delims=" %%a in ("%~dp0SomeFiletogoThroughlater.txt") do (
  Call:DetectDir "%%a"
)

REM Do some stuff after parsing through Files/Directories if needed.  
REM GOTO:EOF below is used to skip all the subroutines below.

REM Using ' CALL:DetectDir "%%a" ' with the for loop keeps the for 
REM loop environment running in the background while still parsing the given file
REM in a clean environment where GOTO and other commmands do not need Variable Expansion.

GOTO:EOF

:DetectDir [File or Folder being checked]

REM Checks if Arg1 is a Directory.  If yes, go to Dir coding. If not, go to File coding.
Dir /b /a:D "%~f1" && Echo Arg1 is a Folder & GOTO:IsDir || Echo Arg1 is NOT a Folder & GOTO:IsFile

REM Checks if Arg1 is NOT a Directory.  If Yes, go to File coding.  If not, go to Dir coding
Dir /b /a:-D "%~f1" && Echo Arg1 is a File & GOTO:IsFile || Echo Arg1 is NOT a File & GOTO:IsDir

:IsDir
  REM Do your stuff to the Folder
GOTO:EOF

:IsFile
  REM do your stuff to the File
GOTO:EOF
```

Answer (score -3):

Can't we just test with this :

```
IF [%~x1] == [] ECHO Directory
```

It seems to work for me.

Comment: This won't work on folders containing a dot. 
It turns out the extension is guessed, not resolved.

Comment: what if the folder name is `myfolder.fld`?