# Get error code from within a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, exit-code

I have a batch file that runs a couple executables, and I want it to exit on success, but stop if the exit code <> 0. How do I do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sounds like you'll want the "If Errorlevel" command.  Assuming your executable returns a non-0 exit code on failure, you do something like:

```
myProgram.exe
if errorlevel 1 goto somethingbad
echo Success!
exit
:somethingbad
echo Something Bad Happened.
```

Errorlevel checking is done as a greater-or-equal check, so any non-0 exit value will trigger the jump.  Therefore, if you need to check for more than one specific exit value, you should check for the highest one first.

Comment: Also, since around Windows 2000, there's a "virtual" environment variable called `%ERRORLEVEL%` that can be tested with `==`, `EQU`, `LSS`, etc.

Comment: Oh, for posterity, to make it stop on error, after :somethingbad, use a "pause" command

Comment: You don't want to use `exit` in there as that kills the shell. Either use `goto :EOF` or `exit /b` so that just the batch file terminates.

Comment: @Jim: You should always delete that variable with `set ERRORLEVEL=` at the start of your batch if you intend to use it, as the function of the pseudo-variable can be shadowed by creating an actual variable with that name. And since the environment is passed from the parent process ... you can never be sure.

Comment: Woah!  I hadn't thought of that.  That's awful.

Answer (score 36):

You can also use [conditional processing symbols](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) to do a simple success/failure check.  For example:

```
myProgram.exe && echo Done!
```

would print `Done!` only if `myProgram.exe` returned with error level 0.

```
myProgram.exe || PAUSE
```

would cause the batch file to pause if myProgram.exe returns a non-zero error level.

Comment: I have to agree this solutions seems much better

Comment: So you could do: `myProgram.exe || exit /b 1` to stop the rest of the commands?

Comment: Thanks @rakslice for this tip. Keeps my script somewhat tidy.

Comment: Looks like you can chain those two... `&& pause || pause` pauses either way, eg. Or, perhaps more useful, `&& (echo success & pause) || (echo fail & pause)`

Answer (score 11):

A solution better than [Hellion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452100/1174942) is checking the `%ERRORLEVEL%` environment variable:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  REM do something here to address the error
)
```

It executes the `IF` body, if the return code is anything other than zero, not just values greater than zero.

The command `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ...` misses the negative return values. Some progrmas may also use negative values to indicate error.

BTW, I love [Cheran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455609/1174942) (using `&&` and `||` operators), and recommend that to all.

For more information about the topic, read [this article](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html)