# How to capture error code of called batch file and fail calling batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have three batch files say parent.bat, child1.bat & child2.bat. The parent batch file calls child1 and child2 batch file. If let's say child1.bat exits with error code 1 then my Parent.bat file does not fails and continue executing child2.bat.

My question is how can I capture error code of child1.bat/child2.bat file and fails the Parent.bat file accordingly.

I have the following code in place:

```
REM CHILD1.bat
echo "Executing CHILD1.bat"
call "%WORKSPACE%/tools/CHILD1.bat"
echo "Executed CHILD1.bat"

REM CHILD2.bat
echo "Executing CHILD2.bat"
call "%WORKSPACE%/tools/CHILD2.bat"
echo "Executed CHILD2.bat"
```

Comment: check `%errorlevel%` after the `call ...` returns. Use `exit /b 1` to exit the failing batch file.

Comment: also, your child process must return something with the `exit /B value` command. Typically `exit /B 0` means success, other values mean failure.

Comment: or the last command or your script goes wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get error code from within a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452046/get-error-code-from-within-a-batch-file)

Comment: sorry, I did a bad dupe search. Found a duplicate of this of course.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think in English *dupe* means the same as in French :-D

Comment: I thought it was an abbrev. for "duplicate".

Comment: In the subsidiary batches, use `exit /b %errorlevel%` Dupe is an abbreviation for 'duplicate'; it should logically be `Dup`, but that would imply a hard `U` as in `cup` - the `e` softens the `u`. `Dupe` also means to hoodwink.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)