# Docker exit code in windows batch file

Tags: docker, batch-file

I would like references on how to check the exit code from docker command like `docker run`, `docker build` etc. in a windows batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get error code from within a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452046/get-error-code-from-within-a-batch-file)

Comment: `if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (echo Something error happened and the above command returned exit code not equal to 0: %errorlevel%) else (Success^^! Exit code is %errorlevel%)` is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Error codes are set to ERRORLEVEL so your batch file might look like this:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    do stuff
)
```

Comment: You can check for any errorlevel but in your case it seems like you would want to be checking for if the errorlevel is greater than 0 which would indicate that something has happened in in your docker stuff.