# How to check if a file exists from inside a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to run a utility only if a certain file exists. How do I do this in Windows batch?

Answer (score 896, accepted):

```
if exist <insert file name here> (
    rem file exists
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
)
```

Or on a single line (if only a single action needs to occur):

```
if exist <insert file name here> <action>
```

for example, this opens notepad on autoexec.bat, if the file exists:

```
if exist c:\autoexec.bat notepad c:\autoexec.bat
```

Comment: If you are dealing with paths with spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script

Comment: @loopkin - `else` is valid, see "if /?" ... "The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF. For example: [...numerous examples of use...]"

Comment: @chris-j Thanks Chris, you're correct, it seems like the parenthesis have to be on the same line as the else. That's what I was doing wrong. I think I'll never get used to the batch syntax :(

Comment: If you're a n00b like me and forget to replace the squiggly brackets too then this won't work. So be sure to remove {} when you {insert file name here}!! Spent an embarrassing 5 minutes realising this :(

Comment: Is this new? I wasn't aware of this syntax until now. However, it works fine on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: @Martin - the extended 'if' syntax has been available since XP I believe.

Comment: if you are running as an administrator your current directory can be reset to system32.. use these lines; \@setlocal enableextensions
\@cd /d "%~dp0"

Comment: One **caveat** of `IF EXIST` construct: It cannot detect Hidden files (files with Hidden attribute).

Comment: I have Win 10 and first if with parentheses does not work.

Comment: This tells you if the target exists, so it could be a file or it could be a directory. It doesn't tell you if the file exists (i.e. if it's a directory, it's not a file)

Answer (score 97):

```
C:\>help if
```

Performs conditional processing in batch programs.

> IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
>
> IF [NOT] string1==string2 command
>
> **IF [NOT] EXIST filename command**

Answer (score 71):

Try something like the following example, quoted from the output of `IF /?` on Windows XP:

```
IF EXIST filename.txt (
    del filename.txt
) ELSE (
    echo filename.txt missing.
)
```

You can also check for a missing file with `IF NOT EXIST`.

The `IF` command is quite powerful. The output of `IF /?` will reward careful reading. For that matter, try the `/?` option on many of the other built-in commands for lots of hidden gems.

Comment: Why the '.' at the end of filename? Is it a typo?

Comment: I quoted the help text from the actual `IF` command built in to CMD.EXE, which had those dots. I don't know why they included them, it does seem inconsistent. Of course, what the `EXIST` keyword actually needs is a valid file name, which may be fully qualified. Other commands use the idiom `[drive:][path]filename` in place of the text `filename.` use here, which is obviously clearer.