# How to test if an executable exists in the %PATH% from a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I'm looking for a simple way to test if an executable exists in the PATH environment variable from a Windows batch file.

Usage of external tools not provided by the OS is not allowed. The minimal Windows version required is Windows XP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a file exists in DOS batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-dos-batch)

Comment: @karlphilip: Definitely no. The question here is quite different.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
for %%X in (myExecutable.exe) do (set FOUND=%%~$PATH:X)
if defined FOUND ...
```

If you need this for different extensions, just iterate over `PATHEXT`:

```
set FOUND=
for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do (
  for %%X in (myExecutable%%e) do (
    if not defined FOUND (
      set FOUND=%%~$PATH:X
    )
  )
)
```

Could be that `where` also exists already on legacy Windows versions, but I don't have access to one, so I cannot tell. On my machine the following also works:

```
where myExecutable
```

and returns with a non-zero exit code if it couldn't be found. In a batch you probably also want to redirect output to `NUL`, though.

**Keep in mind**

Parsing in batch (`.bat`) files and on the command line differs (because batch files have `%0`–`%9`), so you have to double the `%` there. On the command line this isn't necessary, so for variables are just `%X`.

Comment: I like your approach but it would be even better if you could provide the full version, the one that does also use PATHEXT for this.

Comment: For XP you need the loop script (or download where.exe from the RK).  Vista and 7 ships with where.exe.  I know the OP specifically said XP, but for posterity the best answer is always to use `where myExecutable`.

Comment: Ryan: Huh? I don't think I can parse your sentence.

Comment: where.exe (shipped only with Vista and up) has a /q switch which suppresses the need of redirecting output in a script. where /q cmd OR where /q cmd.exe does do the trick.

Comment: i'm a batch scripting beginner and am not sure what the %%x means. On my Windows 7 system i tried typing: for %%X in (myExecutable.exe) do (set FOUND=%%~$PATH:X) and then hit returned. i got this in response: C:\Users\James>for %%X in (cmd.exe) do (set FOUND=%%~$PATH:X)
%%X was unexpected at this time.

Comment: simengineer: Parsing in batch files and on the command line differs (because batch files have `%0`–`%9`), so you have to double the `%` there. On the command line this isn't necessary, so `for` variables are just `%x`.

Comment: great! this works after hours of investigations on this issue

Comment: @RyanBemrose: I think you should post it as a separate answer, even if the OP asked for XP. :) (I think many of us will still find this thread who don't use XP anymore - and it's good that we don't use it anymore.) It's a really good idea (I firstly forgot `where` opportunity), and you would get upvotes - at least from me. :)

Answer (score 105):

Windows Vista and later versions ship with a program called `where.exe` that searches for programs in the path.  It works like this:

```
D:\>where notepad
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe

D:\>where where
C:\Windows\System32\where.exe
```

For use in a batch file you can use the `/q` switch, which just sets `ERRORLEVEL` and doesn't produce any output.

```
where /q myapplication
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO The application is missing. Ensure it is installed and placed in your PATH.
    EXIT /B
) ELSE (
    ECHO Application exists. Let's go!
)
```

Or a simple (but less readable) shorthand version that prints the message and exits your app:

```
where /q myapplication || ECHO Cound not find app. && EXIT /B
```

Comment: Very nice and simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Here is a simple solution that attempts to run the application and handles any error *afterwards*.

```
file.exe /?  2> NUL
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 ECHO file.exe exists in path
```

Error code 9009 usually means file not found.

The only downside is that `file.exe` is actually executed if found (which in some cases is not desiderable).

Comment: the only downside is that "file.exe" is executed (which in some cases is unwanted)

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished via parameter substitution.

```
%~$PATH:1
```

This returns the full path of the executable filename in %1, else an empty string.

This does not work with user-defined variables. So if the executable filename is not a parameter to your script, then you need a subroutine. For example:

```
call :s_which app.exe
if not "%_path%" == "" (
  "%_path%"
)

goto :eof

:s_which
  setlocal
  endlocal & set _path=%~$PATH:1
  goto :eof
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: Interesting trick with `setlocal` but `for %%X in (myExecutable.exe) do (set FOUND=%%~$PATH:X)` is one line solution with `for` used as workaround for `%%~$PATH:X` in order to avoid `call` and `%~$PATH:1`.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a PowerShell option. You can use the [`Get-Command`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJ9ca80JjgAhUQSq0KHY0fDE8QFjAAegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Fmicrosoft.powershell.core%2Fget-command&usg=AOvVaw1rv6QHwtvaF_a8VLZJh1qH) cmdlet passing two items. First give the current dir location with `.\` prefixed, then give just the exe name.

```bsh
(Get-Command ".\notepad", "notepad" -ErrorAction Ignore -CommandType Application) -ne $null
```

That will return true if found local or in system wide paths.

Comment: Nothing better than downvote and run users. If you disagree and are going to go as far as downvoting, then also add a comment to give your reason why you disagree that this is not a good approach at getting the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set found=
set prog=cmd.exe
for %%i in (%path%) do if exist %%i\%prog% set found=%%i
echo "%found%"
if "%found%"=="" ....
```

Comment: Won't work as `for` is not smart enough to parse the contents of `PATH`. It will miss directories with spaces, for example. And even when you use `for /f` with `delims=;` it will not work correctly if a directory contains a `;` and is quoted.

Comment: @Joey, how about string replacement? Replace `;` with `"; "`: `set quotedPath="%PATH:;="; "%"`.

Comment: XP1: Nope, still useless. Try it by appending `"C:\Folder with; semicolon, quoted"` to the path and see what happens. At least here it tries treating every »word« separately which, in a way, is worse than the behaviour before.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this simple solution works, where you check to see if the output matches what you expect. The first line runs the command and grabs the last line of standard output.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (' "xcopy /? 2> nul" ') do SET xcopyoutput=%%i
if "%xcopyoutput%"=="" echo xcopy not in path.
```

Comment: But what if the system environment uses an other language?

Answer (score -1):

Use command : powershell Test-Path "exe which you looking for"

It will return True if its present, otherwise False.

Comment: This won't work. `Test-Path` only checks the specified path, i.e. `Test-Path nuget.exe` will return true only if `nuget.exe` is in the current directory. If nuget.exe is not in the current directory, it will return false, even if it is in a directory listed in the PATH variable. In PowerShell `Get-Command` might work better(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242368/powershell-test-if-executable-in-path), but take into account that for PowerShell the current directory is not in the path.

Comment: As @RonaldZarits pointed out, for full PowerShell support, you can use the Get-Command with two options. First give the current dir location, then give just the exe name. `(Get-Command ".\notepad", "notepad" -ErrorAction Ignore -CommandType Application) -ne $null` will return true if found local or in path.