# Test if executable is in path in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In my script I'm about to run a command

```
pandoc -Ss readme.txt -o readme.html
```

But I'm not sure if `pandoc` is installed. So I would like to do (pseudocode)

```
if (pandoc in the path)
{
    pandoc -Ss readme.txt -o readme.html
}
```

How can I do this for real?

Comment: Maybe which command of zsh in WSL is more useful, if you installed WSL.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can test through [Get-Command (gcm)](http://ss64.com/ps/get-command.html)

```c
if (Get-Command "pandoc.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
{ 
   pandoc -Ss readme.txt -o readme.html
}
```

If you'd like to test the non-existence of a command in your path, for example to show an error message or download the executable (think NuGet):

```c
if ((Get-Command "pandoc.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{ 
   Write-Host "Unable to find pandoc.exe in your PATH"
}
```

Try

```c
(Get-Help gcm).description
```

in a PowerShell session to get information about Get-Command.

Comment: Thanks David. How can I do this gracefully, silencing the big red error?

Comment: Since nobody said, the added "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" kills the big red error.

Comment: I used `where.exe` and checked the exit code, but that was not a PS command.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a function in the spirit of David Brabant's answer with a check for minimum version numbers.

```
Function Ensure-ExecutableExists
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [string]
        $Executable,

        [string]
        $MinimumVersion = ""
    )

    $CurrentVersion = (Get-Command -Name $Executable -ErrorAction Stop).Version

    If ($MinimumVersion)
    {
        $RequiredVersion = [version]$MinimumVersion

        If ($CurrentVersion -lt $RequiredVersion)
        {
            Throw "$($Executable) version $($CurrentVersion) does not meet requirements"
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to do the following:

```
Ensure-ExecutableExists -Executable pscp -MinimumVersion "0.62.0.0"
```

It does nothing if the requirement is met or throws an error it isn't.