# Windows start command

Tags: windows, cmd, operating-system

How the windows start command found application path I means when I use start firefox.exe how Windows know where is firefox.exe, is there simple way to found absolute path only with application name ? I know the environment variables path & others, I searched in all of them and I not found firefox.exe and other programs.

Another thing some programs can be launched directly from cmd without start like iexplorer or notepad but not all the programs regardless the cwd path.

Comment: google for PATH environment variable

Comment: Really you're Firefox.exe is in you're path not in my path every application not necessarily in path

Comment: In addition to the `PATH` variable it also searches your current directory.

Comment: Yeah I know but you can try in every directory it will work

Comment: As far as I know, the `PATH` variable and the current directory are the *only* places the Windows Cmd shell will look for commands, except for a small number of built-ins like `dir`. You're going to need to provide more evidence if you believe differently.

Comment: You can check you're own path variable you will see there is not all the windows program inside and try every program with start without path it's work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if an executable exists in the %PATH% from a windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781772/how-to-test-if-an-executable-exists-in-the-path-from-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Start is the same as typing in Start - Run dialog. Without start CMD preprocesses and then calls CreateProcess on it. Start uses `ShellExecuteEx` which knows many different ways of starting files - *in your case* the main difference that the shell looks up this registry key as well `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` which is where graphical programs register themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are programs in the PATH envinronment's variable. Programs that need the "start" command use the "App Paths" registry key.

See https://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/08/how-the-app-paths-registry-key-makes-windows-both-faster-and-safer/

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new! I'd give this an upvote, but it's not an appropriate question for StackOverflow, thus not an appropriate answer either. If it gets migrated to SuperUser, let me know.

Comment: That was I thought and you provide the answer thank to you. I ask this because I try to make a portable app ( c windows) and using exec function with start command is not an option especially in case of fail I don't find a way to catch the ugly windows error message box.

Comment: @mikl why didn't you say so in the question? That turns it totally on topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @MarkRansom because it was not the main point of my question but you're right it was a mistake, i need to move this question into another section ?

Comment: @mikl this site is about programming questions. Questions about how an operating system finds a file when you type in a command has nothing to do with programming. Questions about how to do something in your own program the same way the operating system does is absolutely about programming. Your question is in the right place, but there's no point in trying to get it back open unless this answer isn't adequate.

Comment: @MarkRansom ok thanks