# How to check if perl is Windows command?

Tags: perl, batch-file, cmd

I would like to write a batch file to silently install Perl MSI. However, the server/PC may have Perl installed, the batch file's flow would be:

1. Check if Perl is installed.
2. If not installed, install it silently.

I know that the command `perl-v` reports Perl version if Perl is installed, but do not have idea how to check whether the `perl` command is executable on the server/PC by windows batch file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781772/how-to-test-if-an-executable-exists-in-the-path-from-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: *"If not installed, install it silently"* I wouldn't be so sure about doing that, especially without a `Do you want to install Perl?` prompt. There are several situations where an installation may not be appropriate, and it may even be that there is already a copy installed, or present on the PATH with a different file name like `perl.5.24.0.exe`. You should leave the user in control of their own PC.

Comment: Installing programs without the user's consent is not good citizenship. Viruses do that. Don't be a virus.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334879/5830574) and [Redirect Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1420965/5830574) might help you.

Run

```
perl -e1 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Perl is not installed
)
```

`perl -e1` simply executes the Perl expression `1` as a one-liner which always is successful if Perl is installed. It produces no ouput at all, except it complains when Perl isn't found. That's why I redirected STDERR to NUL so you will not see any output, even not the error messages.

The `if errorlevel 1` checks whether the returncode of the last command (`perl -e1` in this case) was `>=1`. If Perl is installed and was executable then its returncode will be `0` (meaning success) and the `if` won't trigger.

You could also use `perl -v` but *that* produces output on STDOUT. In that case you would have to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to NUL, like so: `perl -v >NUL 2>&1`.

Comment: This works because _"If a non-existent command is entered for execution, set ERRORLEVEL = 9009"_. Further details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886)

Answer (score 0):

```
>nul 2>nul where perl || echo not installed
```

this checks for perl without trying to run perl.

where prints to STDOUT if it finds the file/command in folders listed in %PATH% or prints to STDERR if it doesn't.