# run a perl script if a file is present

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I want to run a perl script, abc.pl if a file `test.sql` is present in the location

```
C:\directory1.
```

A DOS/Batch Script for the same should be of great helpful. Please assist.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-inside-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if exist "c:\directory1\test.sql" perl [options] [file(s)]
```