# Conditional copying of files from one FTP server to another FTP server

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I want to know how I could add a condition in a batch file to not overwrite always all files every time I transfer the files from one FTP server to another. Here is my code:

```
open rs68.lyon.fr.sopra
dbaq60
sopra*
cd "path file to transfer"
prompt
bin
mget *
disconnect
quit
```

So all I want to do is to test:

- If a file exists already in target directory, then don't copy it .
- If file does not exist in target directory, then copy it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a file exists from inside a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-inside-a-batch-file)

Comment: Very intresting but how can i test in a multiple files, i don't want to put the name of my file but : 

1- look over my record
2- see if my files that i want to copy exist one by one
3- copy if there is no file, copy else not copy

Comment: Just [iterate over the files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop).