# Check file exists before launch it in webpack npm scripts

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, webpack, npm-scripts

I have a package.json like this:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js --mode development --progress --colors",
    "postdev": "if (Test-Path \"./postdev.sh\" ) { echo \"file exists\"; ./postdev.sh }"
  },
...
```

How can I check if file "postdev.sh" exists and then launch it in NPM-scripts section?
I run that command in the terminal and it goes correctly, but if I try to launch that npm-script it says "Unexpected appearance: "./postdev.sh"."

Comment: Solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-inside-a-batch-file

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`path-exists-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-exists-cli) package, a cross-platform tool, to check if a file/directory exists and use `&&` or `||` after to run the next command if exists or not, respectively:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    // other scripts...
    "postdev": "path-exists ./postdev.sh && echo 'Exists' || echo 'Does not exists'"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

on macos or linux try this one for *postdev*:

```
"postdev": "test -f ./postdev.sh && echo 'file exisits' && ./postdev.sh",
```

Comment: Most of our project developers use Windows, so am I, and on Windows it doesn't work :(

Comment: @G.Goncharov check my cross-platform answer. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74738571/7242535

Answer (score 2):

Finnally found a solution (maybe it works only on Windows, but it is enough for me):

```
"postdev": "if exist postdev.sh ( postdev.sh )",
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that `smth && script` or `smth && script || :` are not good solutions. First one still fails when `smth` fails and you won't be able to ignore not existing file case. Second one is bad, because you are ignoring fails from `smth` and `script` together.

Then I prefer to use shell script here:

```
"postinstall": "sh -c 'if [ -f ./dist/postinstall.js ]; then node ./dist/postinstall.js; fi'"
```

It runs postinstall when we have `dist` folder and doesn't ignore postinstall script fails.

Thank you.