# How to check if given path points to a file or a directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

How to find out for example if `C:\Windows\something.tmp` is a file or a directory?

Sometimes applications write their temporary data to a folder with an extension, and deleting a directory differs from deleting a file. So I must call a different subroutine for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test if a file is a directory in a Batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below works both for ordinary and network cases. There is much confusion and has even been heated arguments about distinguishing between files and folders. One reason is that the method familiar from the MS-DOS days (testing for the nul) is no more the valid solution to distinguish between a file and a folder in the Windows command-line. (This is getting complicated.)

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions
if "%~1"=="" (
  echo Usage: %~0 [FileOrFolderName]
  goto :EOF)
::
:: Testing
call :IsFolderFn "%~1" isfolder_
call :IsFileFn "%~1" isfile_
echo "%~f1" isfile_=%isfile_% isfolder_=%isfolder_%
endlocal & goto :EOF
::
:: Is it a folder
:: First the potential case of the root requires special treatment
:IsFolderFn
setlocal
if /i "%~d1"=="%~1" if exist "%~d1\" (
  set return_=true& goto _ExitIsFolderFn)
if /i "%~d1\"=="%~1" if exist "%~d1" (
  set return_=true& goto _ExitIsFolderFn)
set return_=
dir /a:d "%~1" 2>&1|find "<DIR>">nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 set return_=true
:_ExitIsFolderFn
endlocal & set "%2=%return_%" & goto :EOF
::
:: Is it just a file
:IsFileFn
setlocal
set return_=
if not exist "%~1" goto _ExitIsFileFn
call :IsFolderFn "%~1" isfold_
if defined isfold_ goto _ExitIsFileFn
dir /a:-d "%~1" 2>&1 > nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 set return_=true
:_ExitIsFileFn
endlocal & set "%2=%return_%" & goto :EOF
```

Originally from http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd075.htm

Answer (score 1):

[How to test if a file is a directory in a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script)

In short :

```
FOR %%i IN (%VAR%) DO IF EXIST %%~si\NUL ECHO It's a directory
```

But all credits go to [Dave Webb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3171/dave-webb)

Answer (score 1):

You can used `dir /a-d` to tell you

if I check errorlevel it tells me

**With a file**

```
C:\Users\preet>echo. > something.tmp

C:\Users\preet>dir /a-d something.tmp > nul & echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\Users\preet>del something.tmp
```

**with a directory**

```
C:\Users\preet>md something.tmp

C:\Users\preet>dir /a-d something.tmp > nul & echo %errorlevel%
File Not Found
0
```