# How to search string for slashes or colon on Windows command line or in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a function that takes in a parameter and classifies it as a folder name (`FOLDER`), a `RELATIVE_PATHNAME`, or an `ABSOLUTE_PATHNAME`.

What I have so far is this:

```
@echo off
call :classifyInput C:\Users\MikeW
echo C:\Users\MikeW is of type %_inputType%
call :classifyInput documentation
echo documentation is of type %_inputType%
goto :EOF

:classifyInput
SETLOCAL
set _inputType=
rem // a string is a "name of folder" iff it has no '/', '\\' or ':' in it, and a pathname otherwise
echo %1%|findstr /i [\/:] >nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 set _inputType=FOLDER
echo %errorlevel%
rem // a string is a "relative pathname" iff it has no ':' as its second character, and an absolute pathname otherwise
if _inputType == [] & "%1:~2,1% == :" (
    _inputType=ABSOLUTE_PATHNAME
    echo You gave me absolute pathname.
)

ENDLOCAL & set _inputType=%_inputType%
```

And my function so far behaves the same way for both cases.

Furthermore, a Google search for how to find the characters `/`, `\`, `:` is returning nothing useful.

Comment: I am well aware that I didn't handle `RELATIVE_PATHNAME`. That was intentional, as I didn't get to it, as I'm trying to figure out what the hell is going wrong with what I have thus far.

Comment: I'm at the point where I want to just write a program to send my CMD variables to, that would return something back to the CMD process. Problem is I don't know how to do that, either....

Comment: Relative paths may also contain `:` -- think of `C:folder`, for instance...

Comment: @aschipfl It is right that `C:folder` is a  relative path specifying subfolder `folder` in current directory on drive `C:`. But it can be assumed that `C:folder` is approximately to 99.999999999% a mistyped absolute path than an intentionally used relative path. In more than 20 years of Windows computer usage I have never seen that somebody used such a path intentionally as relative path. However, I adapted the code in my answer for checking on absolute path.

Comment: @Mofi, every drive has its own current path since MS-DOS times; back then it was convenient to use relative paths like `D:file.ext` particularly in case you have more than one disk drives; this "relict" is still there in Windows `cmd`. Anyway, I just wanted to point out that there could occur special cases that might treated wrongly in case paths are not handled by path-related functions but by string manipulation functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question to find the characters `/`, `\`, `:` with `findstr` you can just use a regex like this:

```
findstr "[\\/:]"
```

**EDIT**: or if you want to find `\\`, `/` or `:` in a string as described in the comments of your script you can use:

```
findstr /r "\\\\ / :"
```

Because the `\` is the escape character in regex, you'll need to escape it with itself in order to get the real `\`.
[`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) uses the whitespace in its regular expressions as `OR` operator.

Before I let you continue, I'd like to point out some little errors in your code and help you improve it:

- the comparison `_inputType == []` will compare the literal string "_inputType" with the string "[]". If you want to check if a variable is empty or not, use the `if defined var` that will turn true only if `%var%` is not empty (use `if not` for the opposite behaviour) or use `if "%var%" == ""`. But be sure you use the same delimiters because the `==` operator will compare **each single character**: `if abc == "abc"` will never turn be taken but `if "abc" == "abc"` will.
- substring extraction will only work on environment variables that has been defined with `set`. It won't work on arguments variables (nor on loop variables). So `%1:~2,1%` won't get what you want. It will just replace `%1` with the value of the argument in there and give something like `C:\Users\MikeW:~2,1%` for example. If you want to extract from an argument you'll have to set a variable with the value of the argument and extract from that variable:

  ```
  set input=%~1
  rem now you can use %input:~2,1%
  ```

  In your code I read that you want the 2nd character of the input: `%input:~2,1%` will give you the 3rd, not the 2nd. In case of substring, read `%var:~n,k%` as ***k* characters after the *n*-th character**. So what you need is `%input:~1,1%`
- I presume you tried to perform an `AND` operation on this line:

  ```
  if _inputType == [] & "%1:~2,1% == :"
  ```

  Unfortunately, the `AND` and the `OR` operators don't exist in batch, so you'll have to "mock" the `AND` yourself, by using consecutive if-statements (after having applied the modifications proposed above):

  ```
  set input=%~1
  if not defined _inputType if "%input:~1,1%" == ":"
  ```

Finally I got this:

```
@echo off
call :classifyInput C:\Users\MikeW
echo C:\Users\MikeW is of type %_inputType%
call :classifyInput documentation
echo documentation is of type %_inputType%
call :classifyInput Documents\Folder\inside
echo Documents\Folder\inside is of type %_inputType%
goto :EOF

:classifyInput
SETLOCAL
set _inputType=
set input=%~1

rem // a string is a "name of folder" iff it has no '/', '\\' or ':' in it, and a pathname otherwise
echo %input%|findstr /r "\\\\ / :" >nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 set _inputType=FOLDER

echo %errorlevel%

rem // a string is a "relative pathname" iff it has no ':' as its second character, and an absolute pathname otherwise
if not defined _inputType if "%input:~1,1%" == ":" (
    set _inputType=ABSOLUTE_PATHNAME
    echo You gave me absolute pathname.
) else (
    set _inputType=RELATIVE_PATHNAME
)

ENDLOCAL & set _inputType=%_inputType%
```

The script above will result in this:

```
0
You gave me absolute pathname.
C:\Users\MikeW is of type ABSOLUTE_PATHNAME
1
documentation is of type FOLDER
0
Documents\Folder\inside is of type RELATIVE_PATHNAME
```

PS: If you can remove the `echo %errorlevel%`, you can simplify the `:classifyInput` function like this:

```
:classifyInput
SETLOCAL
set _inputType=
set input=%~1

rem // a string is a "name of folder" iff it has no '/', '\\' or ':' in it, and a pathname otherwise
echo %input%|findstr /r "\\\\ / :" >nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
    set _inputType=FOLDER
) else (
     if "%input:~1,1%" == ":" (
        set _inputType=ABSOLUTE_PATHNAME
        echo You gave me absolute pathname.
    ) else (
        set _inputType=RELATIVE_PATHNAME
    )
)

ENDLOCAL & set _inputType=%_inputType%
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands **SET** and **IF** can be used to check if a string assigned to an environment variable contains a specific character or string.

Example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for %%I in ("C:\Users\MikeW" "Folder\FileName" "Folder or file name") do call :ColonBackslash %%I
endlocal
goto :EOF

:ColonBackslash
set "Argument=%~1"

rem Substitute in argument string all colons by nothing and compare this
rem string with unmodified argument string. The argument string contains
rem a colon if the modified and the unmodified strings are not equal.

if not "%Argument::=%" == "%Argument%" (
    echo Colon in argument:        %Argument%
    goto :EOF
)

rem Substitute in argument string all backslashes by nothing and compare
rem this string with unmodified argument string. The argument string
rem contains a backslash if the modified and the unmodified strings
rem are not equal.

if not "%Argument:\=%" == "%Argument%" (
    echo Backslash in argument:    %Argument%
    goto :EOF
)
echo No colon or backslash in: %Argument%
goto :EOF
```

This batch file outputs:

```
Colon in argument:        C:\Users\MikeW
Backslash in argument:    Folder\FileName
No colon or backslash in: Folder or file name
```

Comparing strings with substituted characters/strings with unmodified string can be used to determine type of input string as demonstrated with the batch code below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for %%I in ("C:\Users\MikeW" "C:\Users\Mi:keW" "documentation" "\\server\share\folder" "\\server\share\folder1\..\folder2" "\\server\share\fo:lder" "\\server\" "\\server\share\folder\..\" "%SystemRoot%\..\" ".\Folder" "..\..\Folder" "\Windows" ">:Invalid") do call :classifyInput %%I
endlocal
goto :EOF

:classifyInput
rem Subroutine called with no parameter or with just "" as parameter.
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
set "Argument=%~1"
rem Replace all forward slashes by backslashes in argument string.
set "Argument=%Argument:/=\%"

rem Is the second character a colon and third character a backlash?
if "%Argument:~1,2%" == ":\" goto AbsolutePath

rem Is there a colon anywhere else than at second position in argument?
rem C:Folder is interpreted as invalid argument and not as relative
rem path to subfolder "Folder" of current directory on drive C:.
if not "%Argument::=%" == "%Argument%" (
    echo Invalid argument:  %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Starts the argument with two backslashes?
if "%Argument:~0,2%" == "\\" goto PathUNC

rem Starts the argument with \ for a path relative to current drive?
if "%Argument:~0,1%" == "\" (
    echo Relative path:     %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Starts the argument with .\ for a path relative to current directory?
if "%Argument:~0,2%" == ".\" (
    echo Relative path:     %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Starts the argument with ..\ for a path relative to parent directory?
if "%Argument:~0,3%" == "..\" (
    echo Relative path:     %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Contains the argument a backslash for a path relative to current directory?
if not "%Argument:\=%" == "%Argument%" (
    echo Relative path:     %1
    goto :EOF
)

echo Name without path: %1
goto :EOF

:AbsolutePath
set "Remaining=%Argument:~2%"
rem Is there a colon anywhere else after second position in argument?
if not "%Remaining::=%" == "%Remaining%" (
    echo Invalid argument:  %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Is the first character a drive letter if second character is a colon?
set "FirstIsLetter="
for /F "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" %%# in ("%Argument:~0,1%") do set "FirstIsLetter=%%#"
if not "%FirstIsLetter%" == "" (
    echo Invalid argument:  %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Contains the absolute path also .\ or ..\ in path?
if "%Argument:.\=%" == "%Argument%" (
    echo Absolute path:     %1
) else (
    echo Abs. + rel. path:  %1
)
goto :EOF

:PathUNC
rem Does the UNC path contain also a colon?
if not "%Argument::=%" == "%Argument%" (
    echo Invalid argument:  %1
    goto :EOF
)

set "ServerName="
set "ShareName="
set "Remaining="
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=\" %%A in ("%Argument%") do (
    set "ServerName=%%A"
    set "ShareName=%%B
    set "Remaining=%%C"
)

rem Is there no share name specified after server name in UNC path?
if "%ShareName%" == "" (
    echo Invalid argument:  %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Is there an invalid share name specified after server name in UNC path?
if "%ShareName%" == "." (
    echo Invalid argument:  %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Is there an invalid share name specified after server name in UNC path?
if "%ShareName%" == ".." (
    echo Invalid argument:  %1
    goto :EOF
)

rem Contains the UNC path also .\ or ..\ in remaining path?
if "%Remaining:.\=%" == "%Remaining%" (
    echo UNC path:          %1
) else (
    echo UNC  + rel. path:  %1
)
goto :EOF
```

The output is:

```
Absolute path:     "C:\Users\MikeW"
Invalid argument:  "C:\Users\Mi:keW"
Name without path: "documentation"
UNC path:          "\\server\share\folder"
UNC  + rel. path:  "\\server\share\folder1\..\folder2"
Invalid argument:  "\\server\share\fo:lder"
Invalid argument:  "\\server\"
UNC  + rel. path:  "\\server\share\folder\..\"
Abs. + rel. path:  "C:\WINDOWS\..\"
Relative path:     ".\Folder"
Relative path:     "..\..\Folder"
Relative path:     "\Windows"
Invalid argument:  ">:Invalid"
```

But this batch code is not complete for checking for invalid paths, folder or file names in an argument string. There are still a lot of possible errors not detected by this batch code.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

It would be better to let Windows kernel check if the argument specifies an existing folder or file independent if the argument string is without or with a path of any type and being valid at all. See the topics:

- [How to test if a file is a directory in a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/)
- [How to check if given path points to a file or a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294655/)

And in case of testing for validity on non existing folder/file, just create the file/folder, suppress the error message using `2>nul` (see the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)) and check with `if errorlevel 1` or with `if exist "%~1"` if the folder/file could be created successfully, or if this operation failed because of an invalid folder/file name string, denied access, missing permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

***Preface:*** This does not answer how to search a string for `/`, `\`, `:`; it concentrates on the proper classification of a path!

---

First off, I strongly recommend to avoid to do path classification using pure string manipulation functions, because this is very prone to errors; use path-related features instead!

Then you need to clarify what the routine should output for the following cases:

- input is something like `name`: you call it `FOLDER`, but this could also point to a file instead of a folder, or it does not even exist, so we do not know whether it is a file or a folder; I classify such items `PURENAME`; note that this is nothing but a particular relative path;
- input is something like `.\name`: this I classify `RELATIVE`, similar to you (`RELATIVE_PATHNAME`);
- input is something like `D:\name`: this I classify `ABSOLUTE`, similar to you (`ABSOLUTE_PATHNAME`);
- input is something like `D:name`: there is a colon `:`, so you would call it `ABSOLUTE_PATHNAME`, although this constitutes a path relative to the current directory of drive `D:`, hence I classify it `RELATIVE`;
- input is something like `\name`: there is no drive specified, so I classify it `RELATIVE`, as it points to the root of the current drive;
- input is something like `\\Host\Share\name` (UNC path): this needs to be handled correctly (some commands are not capable of dealing with such paths); I classify them `ABSOLUTE`;
- input contains forward-slashes `/`: many commands do not treat them as path separators, therefore I replace all `/` by `\` before classification;
- input contains quotation marks `"`: they are not valid characters to be used for file and folder names, therefore I remove all of them, as many commands ignore them in paths anyway;
- input contains additional colons `:` beside the one after the drive letter (illegal path), or it contains forbidden characters like `<`, `>`, `|`: the input is not checked for validity;
- input is not checked against existence;

Here is a script that classifies path items you enter in a prompt (empty input terminates script):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:LOOP
rem // Derive user input string here:
set "INPUT=" & set /P INPUT="Enter a path: "
rem // Quit script in case of empty input:
if not defined INPUT exit /B
rem // Remove quotation marks `"`:
set "INPUT=%INPUT:"=%
rem // Replace all `/` characters by `\`:
if defined INPUT set "INPUT=%INPUT:/=\%"
rem // Call classification sub-routine:
call :CLASSIFY ITYPE "%INPUT%"
rem // Return resulting class:
echo "%INPUT%" is of type %ITYPE%.
rem // Loop back to user input:
goto :LOOP

endlocal
exit /B


:CLASSIFY  rtn_class  val_path
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "CLA="
    rem // Check whether argument is empty:
    if "%~2"=="" set "CLA=EMPTY" & goto :RETURN
    rem /* Check whether argument contains wild-cards (like `?` and `*`);
    rem    the `for` loop iterates exactly once in case no wild-cards are present;
    rem    if there are wild-cards, the loop iterates wither zero times (no matching
    rem    items found), or as many times as there are matching items, hence the
    rem    wild-cards becime resolved (replaced), so the `if` condition fails: */
    set "CLA=WILDCARD"
    for %%I in ("%~2") do if /I "%~2"=="%%~I" set "CLA="
    if defined CLA goto :RETURN
    rem // Check whether argument is a pure name:
    if /I "%~2"=="%~nx2" set "CLA=PURENAME" & goto :RETURN
    rem // Check whether argument is a simple relative path:
    if /I "%~d2"=="" set "CLA=RELATIVE" & goto :RETURN
    rem // Check whether argument is a simple absolute path:
    if /I "%~2"=="%~f2" set "CLA=ABSOLUTE" & goto :RETURN
    if /I "%~2"=="%~s2" set "CLA=ABSOLUTE" & goto :RETURN
    rem /* Check whether argument is a complex relative or absolute path; for this,
    rem    the drive is split off from the argument to cover `D:path` items too: */
    set "DRV=%~d2" & set "ARG=%~2"
    if defined DRV call set "STR=%%ARG:*%DRV%=%%"
    if defined DRV if defined STR set "STR=%STR:^^=^%"
    if /I not "%DRV%%STR%"=="%ARG%" set "STR=%ARG%"
    if not defined STR set "STR=."
    rem // The `for` loop iterates once only and is needed to resolve `~` modifiers:
    for %%I in ("%STR%") do (
        rem /* Now check whether argument is an absolute or relative path; for this,
        rem    the argument is converted to an absolute path, related to the current
        rem    working directory first; then the current directory is substituted by
        rem    a temporary drive named `#:`, whose root becomes the current working
        rem    directory temporarily; the argument is again converted to an absolute
        rem    path, related to the temporary working directory; if the result is
        rem    the same as the one from the previous path conversion, the argument
        rem    holds an absolute path, otherwise it holds a relative one: */
        set "LNG=%%~fI"
        set "SHT=%%~sI"
        pushd .
        subst #: . & #:
        set "CLA=ABSOLUTE"
        if /I not "%%~fI"=="%LNG%" if /I not "%%~sI"=="%SHT%" set "CLA=RELATIVE"
        popd & subst #: /D
    )
    :RETURN
    rem // Return resulting class:
    endlocal & set "%~1=%CLA%"
    exit /B
```

The script returns the following classes:

- `PURENAME`: (relative) path consists of a pure name only (similar to your class `FOLDER`);
- `RELATIVE`: path is relative (no drive is given, path does not begin from root);
- `ABSOLUTE`: path is absolute (drive is given, path begins from root, or path is UNC path);
- `WILDCARD`: path contains global wild-cards like `?` and/or `*`;
- `EMPTY`: path is empty (something like `""` has been entered);