# Batch exist test returns true for file\

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to check if my 1st .bat argument is an existing file and **not** a directory, so I tried the simple:

```
if not exist "%~1\." if exist "%~1" echo exists as file
```

but **"%~1\."** tests as existing when **"%~1"** is a file (strange), so the test fails.  I don't see a simple way around the problem.

This does duplicate: [How to test if a file is a directory in a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-to-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script)

Didn't know about the  "**name\NUL**" trick to test for a directory.  I've thought one had to use "**name\.**" to do this.  A scintilla of new info here might be that if exist "**name\.**" is unexpectedly true when "**name**" exists as a file.  This is counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if a file is a directory in a batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-to-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script)

Comment: I think you simply need to remove the dot `.` behind the backslash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if exist "%~1\." echo file or dir&if exist "%~1\.\*" (echo dir) else (echo file)
```

worked for me.