# "if exist Z:\xfile\NUL" returns true for file xfile if Z: is mapped to a network drive

Tags: batch-file, file-exists, subst

I have Z: substituted to a network drive, eg:

```
subst Z: \\fc\c
```

xfile is a **file** (not a directory!) that exists in the root of the substituted drive.  The below statement incorrectly echoes -exists-

```
if exist z:\xfile\nul echo -exists-
```

This makes xfile appear to be a directory, when it's really a file.

A non-substituted drive letter does not cause the problem.  A subst to a non-network drive also does not cause the problem.

Is there a workaround to handle what looks like a subst or if-exist bug?

Comment: If I was to check for a file named xfile in Z:\ I would use If Exist Z:\xfile, If I was checking for a directory named xfile in Z:\ I would use If Exist Z:\xfile\   _I haven't seen the use of `\nul` for well over a decade_.

Comment: What about this work-around: `dir /B /A:D "Z:\xfile" > nul 2>&1 && echo -exists-` to check a directory, and `dir /B /A:-D "Z:\xfile" > nul 2>&1 && echo -exists-` to check a file for existence?

Comment: @Compo If exist  \\server\drv\fname\ will (incorrectly) return true when fname is a file.  I formerly used  whatever\fname\. to check for directory, but that gave false positive when fname was a file.  I was recently told I should use the \nul construct [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-to-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script) but now that is failing in network cases.

Comment: @aschipfl Yes I can do a messy dir workaround but that makes my skin crawl.  Really my problem is a simple one...  I have a .BAT file argument that is a name that could be pointing anywhere (local drive, network path, subst drive).  I want to know IS IT AN EXISTING FILE or IS IT AN EXISTING DIRECTORY or DOES IT NOT EXIST AS EITHER.  In each of these three cases I need to do a particular thing.

Comment: for network paths why don't just map to a drive using `net use`?

Comment: The problem with `if exist` and appending `\ `or `\nul` does not appear to be linked to `subst`, it seems to be the same for a drive mapped by `net use`; so you have to use something other, like querying the `Directory` attribute (by `dir /A` as I suggested above, for instance)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general construct which should work from your .BAT file argument, *(this one assumes it is the first argument `%1`)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=d" %%A In ("-%~a1") Do (
    If "%%B" NEq "" (
        Echo %1 is a directory
    ) Else If "%%A" NEq "-" (
        Echo %1 is a file
    ) Else (
        Echo %1 does not exist
    )
)
Pause
```

Comment: very nice... I can't break that and it solves my problem!  Now I have to hunt down the definition of the 9 chars in %~a1 for future reference.  Doesn't appear to be the same at the attrib output (for instance, there's no indexed "I" entry).

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the \Nul mechanism.

Better use this: (Simply add a backslash)

```
if exist "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\" (
    echo Folder exist
) else (
    echo Folder does not exist
)
```